# UDP Packet NPE - Java

Tags: java, android, sockets, udp

This is running on an android device emulator which is running on the same PC I am trying to send a UDP Packet to.(Is this the error?)

Send code:

```
private byte[] buf = new byte[1];

private DatagramPacket p;

private int port = 4442;
private InetAddress ip; 
private DatagramSocket s;
try {
        ip = InetAddress.getByName(Dataholder.ip);//This one is holding the IP , it is confirmed that it is stored
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {}

    try {
        s = new DatagramSocket(port , ip);
    } catch (SocketException e) {}
 private void sendPacket(int num){////NUM IS 1 DIGIT ONLY!
     buf = Integer.toString(num).getBytes();
     p = new DatagramPacket(buf , buf.length, ip,port);  
     try {
        s.send(p);//Null pointer this line
    } catch (IOException e) {}
 }
```

And receiving code:

```
byte[] data = new byte[1];

    s = new DatagramSocket(4442);
    p = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length);
while(true){

    s.receive(p);
  }
```

I am actually using the PC's IPv4 address...

Comment: Where does the error exactly occur?

Comment: Its commented.... s.send(p);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely your `DatagramSocket` is not being instantiated correctly. It's probably throwing an exception which you are swallowing like a champ.

Don't swallow exceptions like that. Exceptions tell you useful things. If you put something as simple as a `System.out.println` inside of that catch block, you'd probably see that the `new DatagramSocket` is throwing some kind of exception.

Comment: The new DatagramSocket doesnt throw an exception , I cant find out why s.send(p); is causing the VM to crash

Comment: You said you're getting an NPE. If that's the case, `s` is most likely null. If not, look through your stack trace to see where the exception is originating from. Perhaps your packet is null. I don't know.